# Prove $T \mathrm{ker}(A T) = \mathrm{ker}(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (not necessarily invertible), $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Prove the following equation

$$T \mathrm{ker}(A T) = \mathrm{ker}(A),$$

where $\mathrm{ker}(\cdot)$ gives the null space.

Here is my proof:

Let $\mathrm{ker}(A T) = \{x\colon ATx = 0\}$. Then,

$$T \mathrm{ker}(A T) = \{y = T x\colon x \in \mathrm{ker}(A T)\} = \{y = T x\colon ATx = 0\} = \{y\colon Ay = 0\} = \mathrm{ker}(A).$$

Am I right? Thanks!

Conclusion: the proof holds when $T$ is non-singular; for general $T$, we have $T \mathrm{ker}(A T) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(A)$; see the accepted answer provided by Azif00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure that $$\{Tx : x \in \Bbb R^n \textrm{ and } A(Tx)=0\} = \{y \in \Bbb R^n : Ay = 0\},$$ $T$ needs to be invertible. What happens if $T = 0$ and $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! [+1] If $T$ is singular, can we derive $T\mathrm{ker}(A T) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(A)$?  (since the LHS is a subset of the RHS of your equation) Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome! Yes: if $x \in \ker(AT)$ then $Tx \in \ker A$.

Comment: Thanks so much!